# visitParameter of MethodVisitor is never called

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I need to get the method parameter names using asm 5.2. My sources are java 1.8. Looking at the javadoc of `MethodVisitor#visitParameter` it seems that this is exactly what I need:

> Visits a parameter of this method.

But this method is never called. I thought it might be related to missing debugging information, so I compiled the classes with `-g:source,lines,vars`, but this didn't help either.

I resorted to using `visitLocalVariable`, but for the purpose of the utility that I'm writing I don't care about the method's code, so I was looking at providing the `ClassReader.SKIP_CODE` to the ClassReader's accept method.

I'm I missing something? Is there a way to get the parameter names w/o visiting the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile your class with the `-parameters` option to make *javac* include the parameter names. This is why the method is never invoked, without the option your parameter names are not included.

Alternatively, you can check [the `visitLocalVariable` method](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLocalVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-int-) for the parameter names. For non-abstract methods with debug symbols included, the parameter names will be included here.