# how to show method parameter access_flags in java classfile

Tags: java, .class-file

I tried to use `javap -v` on the classfile, but there is no information about method parameter's access_flags as defined in [jvm-4.7.24](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.24) .

Is there another tool or approach to show them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `MethodParameters` doesn't appear in classfile by default. I need to add `-parameters` option to `javac`. Once I add that option, `javap -v` shows parameter names and access_flags. see also:

[visitParameter of MethodVisitor is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596536/visitparameter-of-methodvisitor-is-never-called)
[Drawbacks of javac -parameters flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067477/drawbacks-of-javac-parameters-flag/44075684#44075684)

Comment: With the exception of canonical `record` constructors, which always have the parameter names included.